# mb_substr not truncating Chinese characters properly

Tags: php, character-encoding, substr

When I run this code:

```
$x = '国際交流基金 - 「松島図屏風」他　日米所蔵作品による夢の競演「宗達：創造の波」展開催';
var_dump(mb_substr($x, 0, 80));
```

I expect the string to not be truncated, because it is less than 80 characters.

However, this is the output:

```
string(80) "国際交流基金 - 「松島図屏風」他　日米所蔵作品による夢�"
```

Any idea why mb_substr is truncating it (and not truncating the last character properly)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the proper encoding to be used by the function either:

1. as the fourth parameter - e.g. `mb_substr($x, 0, 80, "UTF-8")`
2. or via [`mb_internal_encoding()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-internal-encoding.php) prior to calling [`mb_substr()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-substr.php)
3. or by [runtime configuration](http://php.net/manual/en/mbstring.configuration.php#ini.mbstring.internal-encoding).

---

[Example:](https://3v4l.org/FNRae)

```
$x = '国際交流基金 - 「松島図屏風」他　日米所蔵作品による夢の競演「宗達：創造の波」展開催';
var_dump(mb_substr($x, 0, 80, "UTF-8"));
```

Output:

```
string(123) "国際交流基金 - 「松島図屏風」他　日米所蔵作品による夢の競演「宗達：創造の波」展開催"
```

Comment: Thank you - I fixed it with #2: mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');